# How to groupby pandas datetime with hourly and day?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to get the count of occurrences for day and hourly from the pandas DateTime column.

data

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
timeData = [
    '2009/6/12 2:00', '2009/6/12 3:00', '2009/6/12 4:00', '2009/6/12 5:00', '2009/6/12 6:00', '2009/6/12 7:00', '2009/6/12 8:00', '2009/6/12 9:00', '2009/6/12 10:00', '2009/6/12 11:00', '2009/6/12 12:00', '2009/6/12 13:00', '2009/6/12 14:00', '2009/6/12 15:00', '2009/6/12 16:00', '2009/6/12 17:00', '2009/6/12 18:00', '2009/6/12 19:00', '2009/6/12 20:00', '2009/6/12 21:00', '2009/6/12 22:00', '2009/6/12 23:00',
    '2009/6/13 0:00', '2009/6/13 1:00', '2009/6/13 2:00', '2009/6/13 3:00', '2009/6/13 4:00', '2009/6/13 5:00', '2009/6/13 6:00', '2009/6/13 7:00', '2009/6/13 8:00', '2009/6/13 9:00', '2009/6/13 10:00', '2009/6/13 11:00', '2009/6/13 12:00', '2009/6/13 13:00', '2009/6/13 14:00', '2009/6/13 15:00', '2009/6/13 16:00', '2009/6/13 17:00', '2009/6/13 18:00', '2009/6/13 19:00', '2009/6/13 20:00', '2009/6/13 21:00', '2009/6/13 22:00', '2009/6/13 23:00',
    '2009/6/14 0:00', '2009/6/14 1:00', '2009/6/14 2:00', '2009/6/14 3:00', '2009/6/14 4:00', '2009/6/14 5:00', '2009/6/14 6:00', '2009/6/14 7:00', '2009/6/14 8:00', '2009/6/14 9:00', '2009/6/14 10:00', '2009/6/14 11:00', '2009/6/14 12:00', '2009/6/14 13:00', '2009/6/14 14:00', '2009/6/14 15:00', '2009/6/14 16:00', '2009/6/14 17:00', '2009/6/14 18:00', '2009/6/14 19:00', '2009/6/14 20:00', '2009/6/14 21:00', '2009/6/14 22:00', '2009/6/14 23:00',
    '2009/6/15 0:00', '2009/6/15 1:00', '2009/6/15 2:00', '2009/6/15 3:00', '2009/6/15 4:00', '2009/6/15 5:00', '2009/6/15 6:00', '2009/6/15 7:00', '2009/6/15 8:00', '2009/6/15 9:00', '2009/6/15 10:00', '2009/6/15 11:00', '2009/6/15 12:00', '2009/6/15 13:00', '2009/6/15 14:00', '2009/6/15 15:00', '2009/6/15 16:00', '2009/6/15 17:00', '2009/6/15 18:00', '2009/6/15 19:00', '2009/6/15 20:00', '2009/6/15 21:00', '2009/6/15 22:00', '2009/6/15 23:00',
    '2009/6/15 0:00', '2009/6/16 1:00', '2009/6/16 2:00', '2009/6/16 3:00', '2009/6/16 4:00', '2009/6/16 5:00', '2009/6/16 6:00', '2009/6/16 7:00', '2009/6/16 8:00', '2009/6/16 9:00', '2009/6/16 10:00', '2009/6/16 11:00', '2009/6/16 12:00', '2009/6/16 13:00', '2009/6/16 14:00', '2009/6/16 15:00', '2009/6/16 16:00', '2009/6/16 17:00', '2009/6/16 18:00', '2009/6/16 19:00', '2009/6/16 20:00', '2009/6/16 21:00', '2009/6/16 22:00', '2009/6/16 23:00',
    '2009/6/15 0:00', '2009/6/17 1:00', '2009/6/17 2:00', '2009/6/17 3:00', '2009/6/17 4:00', '2009/6/17 5:00', '2009/6/17 6:00', '2009/6/17 7:00', '2009/6/17 8:00', '2009/6/17 9:00', '2009/6/17 10:00', '2009/6/17 11:00', '2009/6/17 12:00', '2009/6/17 13:00', '2009/6/17 14:00', '2009/6/17 15:00', '2009/6/17 16:00', '2009/6/17 17:00', '2009/6/17 18:00', '2009/6/17 19:00', '2009/6/17 20:00', '2009/6/17 21:00', '2009/6/17 22:00', '2009/6/17 23:00',
    '2009/6/18 0:00', '2009/6/18 1:00', '2009/6/18 2:00', '2009/6/18 3:00', '2009/6/18 4:00', '2009/6/18 5:00', '2009/6/18 6:00', '2009/6/18 7:00', '2009/6/18 8:00', '2009/6/18 9:00', '2009/6/18 10:00', '2009/6/18 11:00', '2009/6/18 12:00', '2009/6/18 13:00', '2009/6/18 14:00', '2009/6/18 15:00', '2009/6/18 16:00', '2009/6/18 17:00', '2009/6/18 18:00', '2009/6/18 19:00', '2009/6/18 20:00', '2009/6/18 21:00', '2009/6/18 22:00', '2009/6/18 23:00',
    '2009/6/15 0:00', '2009/6/19 1:00', '2009/6/19 2:00', '2009/6/19 3:00', '2009/6/19 4:00', '2009/6/19 5:00', '2009/6/19 6:00', '2009/6/19 7:00', '2009/6/19 8:00', '2009/6/19 9:00', '2009/6/19 10:00', '2009/6/19 11:00', '2009/6/19 12:00', '2009/6/19 13:00', '2009/6/19 14:00', '2009/6/19 15:00', '2009/6/19 16:00', '2009/6/19 17:00', '2009/6/19 18:00', '2009/6/19 19:00', '2009/6/19 20:00', '2009/6/19 21:00', '2009/6/19 22:00', '2009/6/19 23:00',
    '2009/6/20 0:00', '2009/6/20 1:00', '2009/6/20 2:00', '2009/6/20 3:00', '2009/6/20 4:00', '2009/6/20 5:00', '2009/6/20 6:00', '2009/6/20 7:00', '2009/6/20 8:00', '2009/6/20 9:00', '2009/6/20 10:00', '2009/6/20 11:00', '2009/6/20 12:00', '2009/6/20 13:00', '2009/6/20 14:00', '2009/6/20 15:00', '2009/6/20 16:00', '2009/6/20 17:00', '2009/6/20 18:00', '2009/6/20 19:00', '2009/6/20 20:00', '2009/6/20 21:00', '2009/6/20 22:00', '2009/6/20 23:00',
    '2009/6/21 0:00', '2009/6/21 1:00', '2009/6/21 2:00', '2009/6/21 3:00', '2009/6/21 4:00', '2009/6/21 5:00', '2009/6/21 6:00', '2009/6/21 7:00', '2009/6/21 8:00', '2009/6/21 9:00', '2009/6/21 10:00', '2009/6/21 11:00', '2009/6/21 12:00', '2009/6/21 13:00', '2009/6/21 14:00', '2009/6/21 15:00', '2009/6/21 16:00', '2009/6/21 17:00', '2009/6/21 18:00', '2009/6/21 19:00', '2009/6/21 20:00', '2009/6/21 21:00', '2009/6/21 22:00', '2009/6/21 23:00',
    '2009/6/22 0:00', '2009/6/22 1:00', '2009/6/22 2:00', '2009/6/22 3:00', '2009/6/22 4:00', '2009/6/22 5:00', '2009/6/22 6:00', '2009/6/22 7:00', '2009/6/22 8:00', '2009/6/22 9:00', '2009/6/22 10:00', '2009/6/22 11:00', '2009/6/22 12:00', '2009/6/22 13:00', '2009/6/22 14:00', '2009/6/22 15:00', '2009/6/22 16:00', '2009/6/22 17:00', '2009/6/22 18:00', '2009/6/22 19:00', '2009/6/22 20:00', '2009/6/22 21:00', '2009/6/22 22:00', '2009/6/22 23:00',
    '2009/6/23 0:00', '2009/6/23 1:00', '2009/6/23 2:00', '2009/6/23 3:00', '2009/6/23 4:00']


df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': timeData})

df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

Required output

```
hours = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
days = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday']

output = pd.DataFrame(columns=[hours])

output["Day"] = days
```

**Required Output** with values

```
  Day 12a   1a  2a  3a  4a  5a  6a  7a  8a  9a  10a 11a 12p 1p  2p  3p  4p  5p  6p  7p  8p  9p  10p 11p 
Saturday
Friday
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Monday
Sunday
```

Is there a way to group the data with hourly for each day in python?

Comment: `NaN` values???

Comment: updated now....

Comment: @Pluviophile what do you want in the cells?

Comment: count of the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with `%I%p` for hours in `12h` format, then need some processing for remove last `m`, lowercase and remove first `0`, for days use [`Series.dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) and pass to [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), last for original order is used [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
hours = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime('%I%p').str[:-1].str.lower().str.lstrip('0')
days = df["Timestamp"].dt.day_name()

df = pd.crosstab(days, hours).reindex(index=days.unique(), columns=hours.unique())
```

Alternative with assign columns:

```
df['hours'] = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime('%I%p').str[:-1].str.lower().str.lstrip('0')
df['days']  = df["Timestamp"].dt.day_name()

df = pd.crosstab(df['days'], df['hours']).reindex(index=df['days'].unique(), 
                                                  columns=df['hours'].unique())
```

---

```
print (df)
Timestamp  2a  3a  4a  5a  6a  7a  8a  9a  10a  11a  ...  4p  5p  6p  7p  8p  \
Timestamp                                            ...                       
Friday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Saturday    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Sunday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Monday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Tuesday     2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1    1    1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   
Wednesday   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   
Thursday    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   

Timestamp  9p  10p  11p  12a  1a  
Timestamp                         
Friday      2    2    2    0   1  
Saturday    2    2    2    2   2  
Sunday      2    2    2    2   2  
Monday      2    2    2    5   2  
Tuesday     1    1    1    1   2  
Wednesday   1    1    1    0   1  
Thursday    1    1    1    1   1  

[7 rows x 24 columns]
```

If need custom order defined in lists use `ordered Categorical`s:

```
hourscat = ['12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
        '7a', '8a', '9a','10a','11a',
        '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
        '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'];
dayscat = ['Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
        'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday']

hours = pd.Categorical(df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime('%I%p').str[:-1].str.lower().str.lstrip('0'), ordered=True, categories=hourscat)
days = pd.Categorical(df["Timestamp"].dt.day_name(), ordered=True, categories=dayscat)

df = pd.crosstab(days, hours)
```

---

```
print (df)
col_0      12a  1a  2a  3a  4a  5a  6a  7a  8a  9a  ...  2p  3p  4p  5p  6p  \
row_0                                               ...                       
Saturday     2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Friday       0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Thursday     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   
Wednesday    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   
Tuesday      1   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1  ...   1   1   1   1   1   
Monday       5   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   
Sunday       2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2  ...   2   2   2   2   2   

col_0      7p  8p  9p  10p  11p  
row_0                            
Saturday    2   2   2    2    2  
Friday      2   2   2    2    2  
Thursday    1   1   1    1    1  
Wednesday   1   1   1    1    1  
Tuesday     1   1   1    1    1  
Monday      2   2   2    2    2  
Sunday      2   2   2    2    2  

[7 rows x 24 columns]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, why all are nan, Do I updated bad example or is the result expected from the given data

Comment: @Pluviophile - There is another column?

Comment: Based on the timestamps, I need to get the count

Comment: @Pluviophile - Added setup from your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236474/discussion-between-pluviophile-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['day'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.day_name()
df['hour'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%I%p').str[:-1].str.lower().str.strip('0')
hours = df['hour'].unique()
df.groupby(['day', 'hour']).count().unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).reindex(hours, axis=1)
```

output:

```
hour        2a   3a   4a   5a   6a   7a   8a   9a  10a  11a  12p   1p   2p   3p   4p   5p   6p   7p   8p   9p  10p  11p  12a   1a
day                                                                                                                              
Friday     2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  1.0
Monday     2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  5.0  2.0
Saturday   2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
Sunday     2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
Thursday   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
Tuesday    2.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
Wednesday  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

or, to fill NAs:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df['day'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.day_name()
df['hour'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.strftime('%I%p').str[:-1].str.lower().str.strip('0')
hours = df['hour'].unique()
df.groupby(['day', 'hour']).count().unstack(fill_value=0).droplevel(0, axis=1).reindex(hours, axis=1)
```

```
hour       2a  3a  4a  5a  6a  7a  8a  9a  10a  11a  12p  1p  2p  3p  4p  5p  6p  7p  8p  9p  10p  11p  12a  1a
day                                                                                                            
Friday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    0   1
Monday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    5   2
Saturday    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2
Sunday      2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2   2
Thursday    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1   1
Tuesday     2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1   2
Wednesday   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    0   1
```

Comment: Yes, you're right thanks! Not used to work with AM/PM time ;)

Comment: Nice, but how to sort columns?

Comment: @Zephyr you need to save the sorted index and reindex at the end